# DD4T templates for Java and .Net

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, spring

We are implementig dd4t with Java first time and we have some basic question.

Are dd4t templates for Java and .Net same. Or can we use dd4t template installer for 2.0 to use these with Java Spring MVC web application.

For .Net its clearly mentioned to install using installer and for Java on github steps are to import package via content porter.

Secondly is there any document available for setting up dd4t in CME with Java Spring MVC web app, On https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java information available is not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Tridion Templating side DD4T 2.0 Java uses the same TBBs as for .Net, so you can use the exact same installer.

The reason this is not documented in the dd4t-2-java project is mainly because version 2.0 of the templating project came out after dd4t 2.0 for java. This will be corrected when DD4T-Java 2.0 GA will be released.

**Update**: with the release of dd4t-2.0.2, the [dd4t-2 wiki](https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/wiki) was updated with a quick start guide.

Comment: is answer same for 1.31 version also

Comment: Yes, thats the same.